# Can a method access the private member of a parameter?

Tags: c++, class

In C++, suppose that I have a `class MyCls` as follows:

```
class MyCls{
public:
    void fun(const MyCls& x);
private:
    int privatedata;
}
```

My question is that if `fun` can access `x.privatedata`.

Comment: Is it very hard to try this out with a compiler? Granted, the compiler could be wrong and the ultimate answer is in the language specification. But trying it out might give you some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can.

Both are the same class

Comment: +One it's great to see dogs using the internet and C++.

Comment: He is into poddle porn